# Load html page for this tabbed angularjs page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, tabs

I found this jsfiddle sample code which is provides multiple tabs for a single angularjs webapge.

http://jsfiddle.net/helpme128/99z393hn/

I adapted it to my own code. I wanted a certain tab to load a certain webpage `my-custom-page.html`.

Here are my relevant code. The html code;

```
<div id="tabs" ng-controller="StkViewMainCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
            ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}"
            ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mainView">
        <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="one.tpl.html">
    <div id="viewOne">
        <h1>View One</h1>
        <p>Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim
            congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc.</p>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-custom-page.html">
    <div id="viewTwo">
        <h1>View Two</h1>
        <p>Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit
            amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu.</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

The controller code;

```
.controller('StkViewMainCtrl', ['$scope', 'configuration',
        function ($scope, $configuration) {
            $scope.tabs = [{
                title: 'One',
                url: 'one.tpl.html'
            }, {
                title: 'Two',
                url: 'my-custom-page.html'
            }, {
                title: 'Three',
                url: 'three.tpl.html'
            }];

            $scope.currentTab = 'one.tpl.html';

            $scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
                $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
            }

            $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
                return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
            }

        }]);
```

No effect took place. `my-custom-page.html` does not load. `my-custom-page.html` is on the same folder as the single webpage that is being run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html is loading from main page, so if you want to load html from another html file in folder you should use something like ng-include.
So try to change

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-custom-page.html">
<div id="viewTwo">
    <h1>View Two</h1>
    <p>Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit
        amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu.</p>
</div>
```

to

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-custom-page.html">
<div id="viewTwo" ng-include="my-custom-page.html"></div>
```

i changed a code and [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OMs1pWiQkVZ4TyhgFFJQ?p=preview) is a new code on plunker